# Where is the data being stored in Azure IoT hub? and in which format the data being transferred?

Tags: iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-hub

I'm new to Azure,

Can anybody please tel me in which format the data is being transferred from IoT device to IoT hub(device-to-cloud message)? I think it's in JSON.
Also where is the data being stored? Is it xVelocity?

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody please tel me in which format the data is being
>   transferred from IoT device to IoT hub(device-to-cloud message)? I
>   think it's in JSON.

Yes, you are right.

> Also where is the data being stored? Is it xVelocity?

Device-to-cloud messages are retained in an IoT hub's default messages/events endpoint.

For more information you can reference "[Understand device to cloud messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messages-d2c)"